# Laravel hide files on server

Tags: laravel-5

Currently I've put my laravel site online (just for testing). But when I go to for example www.mysite.nl/.env it shows my password etc. for my database. How can I prevent this?

Comment: We need more details. What web server are you running under? (Apache, IIS, etc.) For example, if Apache, try to disable access to specific files with an .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be mentioned that use of `.env` files is intended to be for development only, not production.

Once you're ready to take the site live, the values that you put in the `.env` file should be moved to the server environment variables.

This should be more secure for two reasons:

1. The problem you've discovered, that the `.env` file is accessible, will no longer apply, since there will be no more `.env` file. Plus, this won't require any server configuration changes (`.htaccess` files or similar) to restrict access to the `.env` file.
2. Server environment variables will not be accessible to anyone without shell access to the server.

Comment: Thanks that was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: So I've to add the database credentials in the config/database.php? And then I can remove the .env file?

Comment: If you look at `config/database.php`, you'll notice that the config values look something like this: `'host'      => env('MYSQL_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),`. This line shows that the host value is being read from an environment variable called `MYSQL_DB_HOST` and falling back to `localhost` if that value is not defined. Set that environment variable on your server & you won't have to change your code.

Answer (score 1):

Also keep in mind that .env file should not be reachable by users. Only the public/ folder content must be reachable. Set your server configuration to do it ( not always possible though ).

Otherwise, for your production environment you can simply ommit the .env file and define all the settings directly in app/config/

Some hosters also provide their servers with Forge.

Remember to always put your .env file into the .gitignore file if you are using it.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Removing `.env` alone doesn't guarantee that your code is safe. As the only reason why this happen is that you ignore the default recommended structure which is to only give access for the web server to `public` directory.

Now, let say you removed the `.env` file. Are you sure that:

1. Nobody can access `storage/logs/laravel.log` (or daily rotating log file).
2. Are you sure you're `cache` and `session` data is safe, if you're using file based driver.
3. Are you sure nobody can peek at your compiled blade view under `storage/framework/views`.

Don't ever skip and compromise security to solve your webhosting limitation.

Answer (score 0):

To hide .env on apache server add this below code in top of your htaccess file. this will also hide directory list view and will hide gitignore webpack config and more. hope that helps

```
# Disable Directory listing
Options -Indexes

# block files which needs to be hidden, specify .example extension of the file
<Files ~ "\.(env|json|config.js|md|gitignore|gitattributes|lock)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# in here specify full file name sperator '|'
<Files ~ "(artisan)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, the accepted answer skips over an important detail. Even if the `.env` file is removed, the directory that it resides in should not be accessible in the first place.

Instead of attempting to deny access to a list of files or folders as some people suggest, the web server's *Document Root* should be set to the `/public` folder in a Laravel application. All requests will then be mapped safely starting from `/public`, which means that the source files of your application are not accessible from the web unless you explicitly give access to them.